# WP Mail SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, wordpress, email, smtp

Using wordpress app WP Mail SMTP to send emails using yahoo. here is what i already know:

1. I have configured yahoo to allow insecure apps.
2. My host does not block yahoo's port 465
3. using pingdom i get the error:

Delivery over IPv4 to dnsadmin@uk42.siteground.eu could not be done.

Failed to deliver email for SOA RNAME of pureenv.co.uk (dnsadmin.uk42.siteground.eu) using dnsadmin@uk42.siteground.eu.

DNSCheck failed to deliver email to the email address listed as the one responsible for the zone.

the error log is below, if someone has some suggestions to what could be causing the error.

Versions:
WordPress: 4.9.4
WordPress MS: No
PHP: 7.0.28
WP Mail SMTP: 1.2.5

Params:
Mailer: smtp
Constants: No
ErrorInfo: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Host: smtp.maiil.yahoo.com
Port: 465
SMTPSecure: ssl
SMTPAutoTLS: bool(true)
SMTPAuth: bool(true)

Server:
OpenSSL: Yes
SMTP Debug:
2018-03-25 20:45:08 **Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.maiil.yahoo.com:465, timeout=300, options=array ( ) 2018-03-25 20:45:09 Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known 2018-03-25 20:45:09 Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.maiil.yahoo.com:465 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known) 2018-03-25 20:45:09   SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0) 2018-03-25 20:45:09    SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting**

Comment: some hosts only allow emails on their side eg email.yourdomain.com and block external smtp accounts like Google.  Open a ticket and they will assist you on that

Answer (score 4):

**smtp.maiil.yahoo.com**

mail is spelt with one i not 2

Comment: im doing the biggest face palm right now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Smtps is already deprecated. I think 475 port is blocked by email server
 You can check your 465 port is responding using telnet. I will suggest you to connect using tls by using port 26,587.